# Having trouble understanding why the boxes are not draggable

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am testing a Drag and Drop element. I intend to later edit it to do other things. Right now I followed a book called Sams Teach Yourself HTML5. I have followed the code to the letter and yet it for some unknown reason it refuses to allow the drag and drop to work. I have used the latest Internet explorer Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. I have tried around 4 different code validators to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
Drage and Drop Example
</title>
<style type="text/css">
#target1, #target2, #target3
{
float: left; width: 250px; height: 250px;
padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
}
#draggable1, #draggable2, #draggable3
{
width: 75px; height: 70px; padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
}
#target1{background-color: cyan;}
#target2{background-color: cyan;}
#target3{background-color: cyan;}
#draggable1{background-color: orange;}
#draggable2{background-color: orange;}
#draggable3{background-color: orange;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function start(e) 
{
 e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
 e.dataTransfer.setData("Data",
 e.target.getAttribute('id'));
 e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target, 0,0);
 return true;
}
function enter(e) 
{
 return true;   
}  
function over(e) 
{
 var iddraggable =
 e.dataTransfer.getData("Data");
var id = e.target.getAttribute('id');
if(id =='target1')
 return false;
if((id =='target2')
&& iddraggable == 'draggable3')
return false;
else if(id =='target3')

&& (iddraggable == 'draggable1' ||

iddraggable =='draggable2'))
return false;   
else 
return true;  
}
function drop(e) 
{
 var iddraggable =
 e.dataTransfer.getData("Data");
 e.target.appendChild
 (document.getElementById(iddraggable)); 
 e.stopPropagation();
 return false;      
}

function end(e) 

{

 e.dataTransfer.clearData("Data");

 return true    

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="target1"

 ondragenter="return enter(event)"

 ondragover="return over(event)"

 ondrop="return drop(event)">

 <div id="draggable1" draggable="true"

 ondragstart="return start(event)"

 ondragend="return end(event)">1

</div>
<div id="draggable2" draggable="true"
ondragstart="return start(event)"
ondragend="return end(event)">2
</div>
<div id="draggable3" draggable="true"
ondragstart="return start(event)"
ondrag="return end(event)">3
</div>
</div>
<div id="target2"
ondragenter="return enter(event)"
ondragover="return over(event)"
ondrop="return drop(event)">
</div>
<div id="target3"
ondragenter="return enter(event)"
ondragover="return over(event)"
ondrop="return drop(event)">
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a start parentesis at the line:

```
else if(id =='target3') &&
         (iddraggable == 'draggable1' || iddraggable =='draggable2'))
    return false;
```

It should be like this:

```
else if((id =='target3') &&
           (iddraggable == 'draggable1' || iddraggable =='draggable2'))
    return false;
```

Here's your code working in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4hwqawL/2/
(kind of... still needs improves. But the error is gone)

Comment: Thank you very much. been scratching my head at this for a few days now lol. Just looked in the book it was missing in it too lol

Comment: @NathanR.Watkins, Just a tip... Always ident your code, then it will be easier to target errors like this.. ;)